# Angular - Error for Type not assignable in data bind

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, observable

I'm trying to bind some data from a parent component to its child component and I keep getting the same type error.

I have a table full of cells with movie info and I want to open a modal with further details of a movie when its cell is clicked. This involves some API data fetching.

As such, I have my `app-movie-list` template:

```
</table>
...
    <tbody>
        ...
        <tr *ngFor='let movie of movieList$ | async' (click)="selectMovie(movie.id)">
            <td class="movie-entry ranking">{{ movie.rank }}</td>
            <td class="movie-entry">{{ movie.title }}</td>
            ...
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<app-movie-detail 
    [isDetailDisplayed]="isDetailDisplayed"
    [movie]="(selectedMovie$ | async)"
    ...
>
</app-movie-detail>
```

When a cell is clicked, an API request is made in the component:

```
selectedMovie$!: Observable<MovieDetails>;
...
...
selectMovie(id: string) {
    this.isDetailDisplayed = true;
    this.selectedMovie$ = this.apiManager.fetchMovieById(id);
}
```

The API request in question:

```
fetchMovieById(id: string): Observable<MovieDetails> {
    const endpoint = this.url + "/api/movies/" + id;
    return this.http.get<MovieDetails>(endpoint);
}
```

And finally, in my `app-movie-detail` I just have the input like so:

```
@Input() movie!: MovieDetails;
```

However, I keep getting the same compilation error:

[image]

Can anyone help me understand why I keep getting this type error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The fetchMovieById(id) probably returns `MovieDetails | null`. I assume it fetches the data from a database. So either you handle the case of null in the parent component or you change your `@Input() movie!: MovieDetails;` to `@Input() movie!: MovieDetails | null;`

Comment: I updated my question with the API request. Your suggestion about changing the type on the Input works, however I do prefer to handle the null case before it gets to the child component. Do you have any suggestion on how to do it in the code? Thanks.

Comment: I dont know your complete code but I realized that you already have a list of movies for your table. Therefore you do not have to make another API request. You could get those movie entries and pass them to your selectMovie method and should be working fine since your passing a existing movie in comparison to the api method that may return null

Comment: Unfortunately I do have to make another request. The movie list doesn't contain the details on each movie. The movie details request has to be separate and is the one I am doing right now.

Answer (score 0):

The observable `selectedMovie$` will be suscribed to once the component is loaded due to the async pipe. Until the first request is actually performed you will get null.

You could add a filter to the request like

```js
this.selectedMovie$ = this.apiManager.fetchMovieById(id).pipe(filter(value => !!value));
```

I think I'd not directly pass in the request-result into the databinding though. Instead I would use e.g. a `BehaviorSubject/asObservable` combination and `next()` the result of the fetch (still have the filter on that observable though or have a default/empty details value). That way you could use the info in different places as well if needed (a second async pipe would create another http request).